Convert java.io.Reader to the other Reader with skip reading some chars
I have java.io.Reader as input parameter to the method.
This reader reads file, like "abc\def\jhk";
I need to return from the method an other java.io.Reader, which skips reading "\" chars. So the final file should be: "abcdefjhk".
private Reader convertToFilteredReader(Reader reader) {
    Reader filteredReader = null;
    // some code here
    return filteredReader;
}

I have made this task by converting Reader to String, calling String.replace('\', '') and then converting this String into Reader. But I don't like this solution because of double converting (Reader -> String -> Reader).

maybe an use case for FilterReader

How about trying regex replace function?

@user85421 is spot on

Yes, @Sören, correct, the issue for me is not how to make changes on String, but how not to use String in this process.

Give this a try. Disclaimer: only superficially tested. Comments show how this is simple to reuse.
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.FilterReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

/**
 * Subclasses should implement isExcluded to determine which characters will be
 * 'swallowed' by the Reader
 *
 * @author g00se
 * @version 1.0
 */
public abstract class ExclusionReader extends FilterReader {
    private char[] singleCharBuf = { 0 };

    public ExclusionReader(Reader in) {
        super(in);
    }

    // Testing only
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Reader downstream = args.length < 1 ? new StringReader("abc\\def\\ghi")
                : Files.newBufferedReader(Path.of(args[0]));
        try (Reader in = new BackslashExcludingReader(downstream);
                Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(System.out)) {
            in.transferTo(out);
        }
    }

    public abstract boolean isExcluded(int codePoint);

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        int result = read(singleCharBuf, 0, 1);
        return result > -1 ? singleCharBuf[0] : result;
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] b) throws IOException {
        return read(b, 0, b.length);
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] buf, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        if (len <= 0) {
            if (len < 0) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            } else if ((off < 0) || (off > buf.length)) {
                throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
            }
            return 0;
        }
        int charsCopied = 0;
        int c = -1;

        while ((charsCopied + off) < len && (c = in.read()) > -1) {
            if (!isExcluded(c)) {
                buf[off + charsCopied] = (char) c;
                charsCopied++;
            }
        }

        int returnVal = charsCopied;
        if (charsCopied == 0) {
            returnVal = Math.min(charsCopied, c);
        }
        return returnVal;
    }

    // What YOU need
    static class BackslashExcludingReader extends ExclusionReader {
        public BackslashExcludingReader(Reader in) {
            super(in);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isExcluded(int codePoint) {
            return codePoint == '\\';
        }

    }
}


BTW no need to override read(char[]) (same code already in Reader)

@user85421 - right yes

The best way to deal with this is to use a FilterReader that filters out BOMs. They exist. iirc there could be one in Commons IO. tbh I'm surprised this functionality is not already in base Java

"not already in base Java" -- StandardCharsets.UTF_16 and StandardCharsets.UTF_32 should filter out BOMs (UTF-8 should not use BOM at all, but seen in some Windows/Microsoft applications)

new String(new byte[]{(byte)-2,(byte)-1,0,79,0,75}, "UTF-16") --> "OK" (no ZERO-WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE at first position)

... should filter out BOMs ... Strangely, that's what I thought, but it's not the case (at least here): String s = Files.readString(Path.of("people.utf_16be.csv"), StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE);s.codePointAt(0);$16 ==> 65279 (Jshell) (File with BOM)

@user85421 I just realised I posted my first comment in the wrong place. It should be HERE Also your comment here is not correct, as all reading methods must remain undelegated (iow must be overridden) as otherwise they will escape filtering

well, there is a difference between UTF_16  and UTF_16BE (or UTF_16LE) - later ones do NOT suppress the BOM (no need for BOM?) - from the link I posted above: "When decoding, the UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, UTF-32BE, and UTF-32LE charsets interpret the initial byte-order marks as a ZERO-WIDTH NON-BREAKING SPACE ... When decoding, the UTF-16 and UTF-32 charsets interpret the byte-order mark at the beginning of the input stream to indicate the byte-order ..."

@user85421, I fear I've confused you as well ;) We're both now posting comments about BOM reading in a question that has absolutely nothing to do with BOMs. This discussion is of value but the comments should be moved here
